# Programmatically drawing the lines in a delphi drawgrid and merge cells

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, pascal

I want to disable the gridlines in a drawgrid and draw the grid lines myself for every other columns. Row lines are not needed.

I want to merge two cells in the fixed area so that it looks like as it is one column, like in this picture:

[image: Grid with merged columns]

I have added this code to the `ondrawcell` event of the drawgrid to achieve this:

```
procedure Tbookings3_Frm.bgridDrawCell(Sender: TObject; ACol, ARow: Integer;
  Rect: TRect; State: TGridDrawState);
var
  CellIndex: Integer;
    s:string;
  x:integer;
begin
  CellIndex := (ARow * bgrid.ColCount) + ACol;

  if gdFixed in State then
  begin
    bgrid.Canvas.Brush.Color := clskyblue;
  end
  else if (State * [gdSelected, gdHotTrack]) <> [] then
  begin
    bgrid.Canvas.Brush.Color := clHighlight;
  end
  else
  begin
    bgrid.Canvas.Brush.Color := Cells[CellIndex].BkColor;
  end;



  bgrid.Canvas.FillRect(Rect);

  if gdFixed in State then
    Frame3D(bgrid.Canvas, Rect, clHighlight, clBtnShadow, 1);

  if gdFocused in State then
    bgrid.Canvas.DrawFocusRect(Rect);

//---------------

  with (Sender as TDrawGrid).Canvas do
  begin
     // set font
    Font.Color := CLblack;
    FillRect(Rect);

    if ARow = 2 then
    begin
        x := (Rect.Right - Rect.Left - TextWidth(days_h[ACol])) div 2;
        TextOut(Rect.Left + x, Rect.Top + 2, days_h[ACol]);
    end;
  if ARow = 1 then
     begin
       x := (Rect.Right - Rect.Left - TextWidth(sun_mon[ACol])) div 2;
       TextOut(Rect.Left + x, Rect.Top + 2, sun_mon[ACol]);

     end;
  if ARow = 0 then
     begin
        x := (Rect.Right - Rect.Left - TextWidth(mon[ACol])) div 2;
        TextOut(Rect.Left + x, Rect.Top + 2, mon[ACol]);
      end;

  if (Acol = 0) and (ARow > 2) then
     begin
        s:=rooms[Arow];
        x := (Rect.Right - Rect.Left - TextWidth(s)) div 2;
        TextOut(Rect.Left + x, Rect.Top + 2, s);
     end;

//-------------------------------------------------



  end; //end canvas
//----------------
  if gdFocused in State then
    bgrid.Canvas.DrawFocusRect(Rect);
end;
```

Comment: Please embed the image directly in the question. Don't make everyone use a download service to fetch the image. At the very least, use a real image-hosting service so we can view the image without a separate download.

Comment: I embedded the picture for him.

Answer (score 1):

You need to disable the grid's native gridlines, and then you can draw your own gridlines surrounding each cell in the `OnDrawCell` event as needed.  The `TRect` represents the inside area of the cell being drawn, but you can draw outside of that Rect as well.  To make two cells appear merged, you would simply not draw a gridline between them.

Comment: I am very new to this field. Can you please give some sample code